# DICT() and MATPLOTLIB?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I created a dictionary to match the feature importance of a Decision Tree in sklearn with the corresponding name of the feature in my df. Here the code below:

```
   importances = clf.feature_importances_
   feature_names = ['age','BP','chol','maxh',
          'oldpeak','slope','vessels',
          'sex_0.0','sex_1.0', 
          'pain_1.0','pain_2.0','pain_3.0','pain_4.0',
          'bs_0.0','bs_1.0',
          'ecg_0.0','ecg_1.0','ecg_2.0',
          'ang_0.0','ang_1.0',
          'thal_3.0','thal_6.0','thal_7.0']
   CLF_sorted = dict(zip(feature_names, importances))
```

in output I obtained this:

```
   {'BP': 0.053673644739136502,
    'age': 0.014904980747733202,
    'ang_0.0': 0.0,
    'ang_1.0': 0.0,
    'bs_0.0': 0.0,
    'bs_1.0': 0.0,
    'chol': 0.11125922817930389, ...}
```

as I expected. I have two question for you:

1. how could I create a bar plot where the x-axis represents the `feature_names` and the y-axis the corresponding `importances`?
2. if it is possible, how could I sort the bar plot in a descending way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'feature': feature_names , 'importance': importances})
df.sort_values('importance', ascending=False).set_index('feature').plot.bar(rot=0)
```

demo:

```
d ={'BP': 0.053673644739136502,
    'age': 0.014904980747733202,
    'ang_0.0': 0.0,
    'ang_1.0': 0.0,
    'bs_0.0': 0.0,
    'bs_1.0': 0.0,
    'chol': 0.11125922817930389}

df = pd.DataFrame({'feature': [x for x in d.keys()], 'importance': [x for x in d.values()]})

In [63]: import matplotlib as mpl

In [64]: mpl.style.use('ggplot')

In [65]: df.sort_values('importance', ascending=False).set_index('feature').plot.bar(rot=0)
Out[65]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x8c83748>
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! I am using Python 2.7 which returns me an error like this: "name 'd' is not defined". Any solution for this problem? Sorry for my basic question but I started to use python seriously just one month ago.

Comment: @ElenaPhys, try to use `df = pd.DataFrame({'feature': feature_names , 'importance': importances})` instead. `d` - is a dictionary that you've created from `importances` and `feature_names `

Comment: @ElenaPhys, did it help?

Comment: how could I set the size of the plot? I read the pandas documentation, but I found only the way to adjust the bars.

Comment: @ElenaPhys, sure, try: `.plot.bar(rot=0, figsize=(12, 10))`. Pandas plot functions inherit matplotlib parameters...